# How can I create a TTY to attach gdb to/detach bash from its tty?

Tags: bash, gdb, tmux, tty

I have two terminals open (within tmux). In the first, I type:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/4
```

And in the second

```
$ gdb brokenprogram
(gdb) tty /dev/pts/4
```

This successfully redirects the output of the process being debugged to the first terminal. However, when I type in the first terminal, `bash` and `brokenprogram` are competing to read input. How can I stop bash from listening to any further keypresses?

Comment: hm.. interesting question. IMHO you can try redirect the `stdin` for the 1st terminal's bash to another descriptor via `exec 5<&0` or such, but never tried this.

Comment: One suggestion I've seen is to use `sleep 10000`, but that feels hacky, and also probably doesn't always forward `^C` correctly

Comment: just found this: http://superuser.com/q/145605/83626 - check it maybe helps

Answer (score 1):

I think the suggestion to run `sleep` so the shell doesn't access the tty is fine, but an alternative is to use `gdbserver`.

On /dev/pts/4:

```
$ gdbserver localhost:12345 brokenprogram
Process brokenprogram created; pid = 9134
Listening on port 12345
```

On the other terminal:

```
$ gdb brokenprogram
(gdb) target remote localhost:12345
Remote debugging using localhost:12345
<gdb chatter that the process is stopped at _start()>
(gdb) continue
```

And then you can interact with brokenprogram on /dev/pts/4.